# How to pass global system env variables to jenkins dsl job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have set a global jenkins env variable but for some reason my build is not picking system env variable. There is no error, but its not executing the if condition.

Pls point me where i'm wrong and how to use already set global system env variables in jenkins dsl.

Env variable set :

```
root@amp-jenkins-0:/var/jenkins_home/jobs# cat generator-job/builds/11/injectedEnvVars.txt | grep eks
kubernetes_cluster_name=xx-xxx
```

Comment: This should work `build.environment.get("BUILD_NUMBER")` Replace BUILD_NUMBER with the variable you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
job('example') {
  environmentVariables {
    keepSystemVariables(true)
  }
}
```

Description is [here](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.FreeStyleJob.environmentVariables-keepSystemVariables)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

getBinding().getVariables()['kubernetes_cluster_name']